# SSAS MDX Calculated Member: 3 months moving average not working

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, mdx-query, analysisservices

I have some `MDX` code to produce a 3 Months Average.

It doesn't work and I can't find the problem.

I've researched many sites - I'm trying to emulate the code found for similar scenarios but can't see what I'm doing wrong.

[Calculated Member in SSAS MDX not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8zOxk.jpg)

I have a **Fiscal Time dimension** and a **Fiscal Time Hierarchy** in it

[Fiscal Time Dimension](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1RLkV.jpg)

I expect to create a new measure which shows the average of the current month + the 2 past Months (3 Months Average), but for now, it only shows me NULL values

[Result not showing the average, showing NULLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKIl8.jpg)

Does anyone spot my mistake?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi, what do you mean by "It doesn't work" ? Do you have an incorrect result or no result at all ?

Comment: Hi Hugo, I would expect the calculated member to show the average of the month and the 2 previous months, but right now is only throwing me nulls. I'm adding the corresponding image to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with this formula (I tried to respect your dimension and measure name, tell me if I'm wrong):

`AVG({[FISCAL TIME].[FISCAL TIME HIERARCHY].CURRENTMEMBER.LAG(2):[FISCAL TIME].[FISCAL TIME HIERARCHY].CURRENTMEMBER},[Measures].[AMOUNT or UNIT - WARRANTY])`

Apparently, you can't specify a level (like `FISCAL MONTH (Label Only)`) when you're using hierarchy.

Be carefull, this formula works when you're browsing at "month" level, but if you go to day level, it will calculate 3 moving days (same principe for year and all other levels).

If you want to fix your calculation at 3 moving months,no matter the granularity, (month or lower) I would suggest you to use PARALLELPERIOD function :

`AVG({PARALLELPERIOD([FISCAL TIME].[FISCAL TIME HIERARCHY].[FISCAL MONTH (Label Only)],2,[FISCAL TIME].[FISCAL TIME HIERARCHY].CURRENTMEMBER):[FISCAL TIME].[FISCAL TIME HIERARCHY].CURRENTMEMBER},[Measures].[AMOUNT or UNIT - WARRANTY])`

I would also suggest you to add a scope to set the value of this calculation at `NULL` when you're at a higher level than Month.

I really hope it will solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Hugo, both approaches work. I'm really new to SSAS MDX, how would you add a scope to the below code so that it only calculates at the month level? 
.
`AVG({PARALLELPERIOD([FISCAL TIME].[FISCAL TIME HIERARCHY].[FISCAL MONTH (Label Only)],2,[FISCAL TIME].[FISCAL TIME HIERARCHY].CURRENTMEMBER):[FISCAL TIME].[FISCAL TIME HIERARCHY].CURRENTMEMBER},[Measures].[AMOUNT or UNIT - WARRANTY]) `
.
And also, what could I do to aggregate the average of the months to the quarter level, the average of the quartes to the half level and the average of the halves to the year level?